# Add transparency to MarkerImage Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Having something like :

```
f (imgURL != '') {
    return new google.maps.MarkerImage(imgURL);
}
```

is there any way of adding some transparency to this MarkerImage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a GIF/PNG as the source image, and set transparency on it.